# App Store upload. Problem with SDK

Tags: iphone, sdk, app-store-connect, ios

I just tried to upload a completed app via iTunes Connect, and I received the following error:

**The binary you uploaded was invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK.**

I upgraded to the 4.0 SDK. I got this same exact error with the PREVIOUS version of the SDK as well. 3.?.? (whatever it was). Now in Xcode, I no longer have the option to select a previous version of the SDK.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

you must download "Application Loader."

Comment: Goto build/distribution-phoneos compress the app file then upload that through installed application loader

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure when you build the .app bundle for distribution, that you are building for "Device" and "Distribution" in the drop down menu of the main XCode screen.
2. Make sure in the "Project Settings" that you have set the base SDK to 4.0 and your deployment target SDK to 3.0 (or whatever you want it to be).. both settings are found in that "Build" menu.  Settings are for the "Distribution" configuration

This will build the app with the latest SDK but allow users of 3.0 (or whatever you chose) to use the app so long as you only included API that was available in 3.0 or below.

Comment: I JUST received an email from Apple notifying me that iTunes Connect will no longer accept uploads submitted in the binary format as of July 22. They say you must download "Application Loader."

Thank you for your input! :)

Comment: That's interesting... I wonder why they are switching.  Maybe offloading some static analysis to the application loader now?  Thanks for the comment update